# Ajax Modal Popup Extender and JQM

Tags: asp.net, jquery-mobile

in my aspx mobile page when I sent an ajax request to server I got this error:

```
Sys.ArgumentTypeException: Object of type 'AjaxControlToolkit.ModalPopupBehavior' cannot  be converted to type 'AjaxControlToolkit.ModalPopupBehavior'. Parameter name: instance
```

I don't know exactly what happened but I'm sure its related to jquery that I have in my page, because I check this page without including jqm and it works correctly. Thanks

Lines run when button clicked in asp page:

```
string message = "blahbalahblahblah...";
MessageBoxInfo.Show(MessageBox.MessageType.Error, message, 110, 350);
return;
```

In my Control(MessageBox.ascx) I have:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButtonTargetControl" runat="server"></asp:LinkButton>
<ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtenderMessage" runat="server" TargetControlID="LinkButtonTargetControl" 
    PopupControlID="MessageBox" OkControlID="ButtonOK" CancelControlID="CloseButton" BackgroundCssClass="messagemodalbackground" />

    <asp:Panel ID="MessageBox" runat="server" style="display:none;">
         <asp:HyperLink runat="server" id="CloseButton" >
            <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server"  ImageUrl="../images/Message/close.png" AlternateText="Close" />
        </asp:HyperLink>
        <p><asp:Literal ID="litMessage" runat="server"></asp:Literal></p>
    </asp:Panel>
```

And the show method is as below(MessageBox.ascx.cs):

```
public void Show(MessageType messageType, string message, int height, int width)
{
    CloseButton.Visible =  ShowCloseButton;
    litMessage.Text = message;
    MessageBox.Height = height;
    MessageBox.Width = width;
    MessageBox.CssClass = messageType.ToString().ToLower();
    ModalPopupExtenderMessage.Show();
    this.Visible = true;
}
```

Also I should mention that the show method called each time and everything inside it such as width height... set ok but if you check it in firebug you see that display:none is still remain!

Comment: Please add some lines of code more.. how do you get ModalPopupExtenderMessage?

Comment: I just updated my post. take a look dude

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the runtime  is supposed to use two different assemblies called `AjaxControlToolkit.ModalPopupBehavior`, let's say `AjaxControlToolkit.ModalPopupBehavior1` and `AjaxControlToolkit.ModalPopupBehavior2`.

`MessageBoxInfo` is coming from `AjaxControlToolkit.ModalPopupBehavior1` and
`MessageBox.MessageType` is coming from `AjaxControlToolkit.ModalPopupBehavior2`

So the `MessageBoxInfo.Show(MessageBox.MessageType.Error, message, 110, 350);` throws a fake conversion error.

**If you try another `Show()` override, without `MessageBox.MessageType` it works, true?**

Real solution, if you can't find the reasom could be a workaround using reflection: 
**to get the assemlby at runtime from `MessageBoxInfo` object**
and **using it to instantiate a `MessageBox.MessageType`**.

Comment: thanks for reply, but I dont understand your meaning completely. show() method without type is not acceptable!

Comment: @MattStone sorry! Where does MessageBoxInfo come from?

Comment: first I register my control in the page `<%@ Register Src="../controls/MyMessageBox.ascx" TagName="MyMessageBox" TagPrefix="uc2" %>` then I added in updatePanel `<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel" runat="server" UpdateMode = "Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
             <uc2:MyMessageBox ID="MyMessageBoxInfo" runat="server" ShowCloseButton="true" />`